# A probability measure on $[0,1]$ with given moments $a_0,\ldots,a_k$

Tags: probability-theory, moment-problem

This is another problem I found trying to obtain properties related to finite exchangeable sequences of random variables. Anyway, I am asking the question here because I think the answer could be already well known..

---

**Problem:** Let $1=a_0 \ge a_1 \ge \cdots \ge a_k \ge 0$ be $k+1$ fixed real numbers. Is it possible to find a probability measure $\mu$ on $([0,1],\mathscr{B}[0,1])$ such that for all $i=0,1,\ldots,k$ it holds
$$
\int_{[0,1]}t^i \mu(\mathrm{d}t)=a_i\,\,?
$$

---

The problem, without the additional assumption of non-increasing moments, is called *reduced Hausdorff moment problem*, but I didn't find a characterization of the cases when the solution is affirmative [indeed, this is going to be not always affirmative]..

Comment: Which parts of this problem are not answered [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem)?

Comment: There it is assumed that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is infinite; for sure, here we could say "the answer is affirmative if and only if there exists $a_{k+1},a_{k+2},\ldots$ satisfying those conditions." But can we do it more explicitely, considering the additional assumption above?

Comment: OK, I had missed the "finite number of moments" part. So, a necessary condition is that all the differences $\Delta^na$ one can form using $(a_i)_{i\leqslant k}$ have the correct sign.

Comment: See theorem 1 [there](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0PDN9S0ho-oC&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=reduced+hausdorff+moment+problem&source=bl&ots=1cnUZ7dgSK&sig=EuUHfpEimQGNOQIFmSoK17y2ZjA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCk-G71ZLLAhWDfxoKHS-RCSEQ6AEIZjAH#v=onepage&q=reduced%20hausdorff%20moment%20problem&f=false).